# My reputation is less than my quarter reputation!

Tags: support

[image]
[This](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/275/quarter/aviation/2015-04-01/8482#8482) is pretty amazing and interesting for me! Which of them (total or quarter) is actually the correct one? This picture was taken on 7th June 2015, 9:00 PM (GMT +5:30).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation) on Meta.SE.

> The discrepancy is by design:
>
> - **Total reputation** is your current reputation on the site (accurate to within 24 hours).
> - **Month reputation** is the amount by which your reputation changed that month, *excluding "private" reputation events*. Certain reputation events are excluded from your public user profile, such as deleted posts or downvotes, so those are excluded from the leagues as well.
>
> In other words, "total reputation" includes private reputation events, while "month reputation" does not.